# ImageChops not seeing file paths

Tags: python, operating-system, python-imaging-library

I want to compare pictures in 2 lists, 1 to 1 accordingly. So I do below:

(Python 2.7 + Windows)

```
Nov_list = [
'C:\Animals\Nov 2014\Loxodonta africana Nov 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Nov 2014\Haliaetus vocifer Nov 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Nov 2014\Xerus sp. Nov 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Nov 2014\Actophilornis africanus Nov 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Nov 2014\Hystrix cristata Nov 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Nov 2014\Macropus agilis Nov 2014.jpg', ]

Mar_list = [
'C:\Animals\Mar 2014\Loxodonta africana Mar 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Mar 2014\Haliaetus vocifer Mar 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Mar 2014\Xerus sp. Mar 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Mar 2014\Actophilornis africanus Mar 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Mar 2014\Hystrix cristata Mar 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Mar 2014\Macropus agilis Mar 2014.jpg', ]

for a, b in zip(Nov_list, Mar_list):

    diff = ImageChops.difference(a, b).getbbox()
    print diff
```

it gives an error:

```
“AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'load'”.
```

It seems the code is not seeing the file and its locations. I tried them with double "\” and also tried added the **r’** at the beginning of the paths, but neither works.

---

Thanks to NeoWu's help, the code changed to below and works:

```
for a, b in zip(a20141104, a20141110):
    im1 = Image.open(a)
    im2 = Image.open(b)

    diff = ImageChops.difference(im1, im2).getbbox()
        print a + b + 'is: ' + str(diff)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Nov_list = [
'C:\Animals\Nov 2014\Loxodonta africana Nov 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Nov 2014\Haliaetus vocifer Nov 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Nov 2014\Xerus sp. Nov 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Nov 2014\Actophilornis africanus Nov 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Nov 2014\Hystrix cristata Nov 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Nov 2014\Macropus agilis Nov 2014.jpg']

Mar_list = [
'C:\Animals\Mar 2014\Loxodonta africana Mar 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Mar 2014\Haliaetus vocifer Mar 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Mar 2014\Xerus sp. Mar 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Mar 2014\Actophilornis africanus Mar 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Mar 2014\Hystrix cristata Mar 2014.jpg', 
'C:\Animals\Mar 2014\Macropus agilis Mar 2014.jpg']
```

You should delete the last ',' off the list.

Comment: um,i got it. ImageChops.difference(a, b).getbbox(), the args of func 'difference(im1,im2)' should not be 'str'. u should import Image, and [im = Image.open("xxx.jpg")]